# How do I add ambient occlusion or show shadows for the craters in my moon object?

Tags: node-editor, emission, ambient-occlusion

I really don't know how to use nodes so I'm wondering how to use ambient occlusion to show that there are craters on my moon while the moon has emissions on. I want to do this by having some shadows on the craters.
I am also wondering how I can use emissions as a light source because now I am using a sunlight source inside the moon for my background.
[image: nodes][image: emissions on]
[image: emissions off]

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are several solution, but you could simply use the *Input > Ambient Occlusion* node as a factor between 2 *Emission* nodes. Use a ColorRamp between the *AO* and the *Mix Shader* if you ever need to tweak the contrasts:

[image]